# Moving Sprite Diagonally

Tags: c#, monogame

So when I press <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> in my keyboard sprite moves but it doesn't want to go diagonal its like you can only press 1 button at a time here is my code.

What I want it to do is when you say for example press <kbd>w</kbd> and <kbd>d</kbd> it goes north east. Same goes for other keys

```
class Player
{
    Texture2D playertexture;
    Vector2 playerposition;



    public Player(Vector2 playerposition, Texture2D playertexture)
    {
        this.playertexture = playertexture;
        this.playerposition = playerposition;
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.D)) //right
        {
            playerposition.X += 1;

        }
        else if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.A)) //left
        {
            playerposition.X -= 1;

        }
        else if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.W)) //up
        {
            playerposition.Y -= 1;

        }
        else if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.S)) //down
        {
            playerposition.Y += 1;

        }

    }
    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {

        spriteBatch.Draw(playertexture, playerposition, Color.White);


    }
}
```

Comment: This is because you are excluding other buttons with `else if`. Just use standalone `if` for each button check.

Comment: im so dumb thanks for helping me omg hahaha I was stressing over it for about an hour now hahahahaha thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You can easily sum up all pressed keys and get a "final" movement Vector ranging from -1,-1 to 1,1

```
    public Vector2 GetPlayerMovement()
    {
        Vector2 r = Vector2.Zero;
        KeyboardState ks = Keyboard.GetState();

        if (ks.IsKeyDown(MOVEUP))
            r.Y -= 1;
        if (ks.IsKeyDown(MOVEDOWN))
            r.Y += 1;
        if (ks.IsKeyDown(MOVELEFT))
            r.X -= 1;
        if (ks.IsKeyDown(MOVERIGHT))
            r.X += 1;

        return r;
    }
```

MOVEUP/DOWN/LEFT/RIGHT is representing the keys WSAD